# Why do I need an extra wrapper while returning in React?

Tags: reactjs

So, I am starting to learn React and I encountered this code and I am really confused.

The following code gives Error:

```
function getNum() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
}

class Number extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const num = getNum();
    let msg;
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
      msg = (
        <div>
          <h2>Even Number</h2>
          <p>The number is: {num}</p>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      msg = (
        <div>
          <h2>Odd Number</h2>
          <p>The number is: {num}</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
    // THIS IS WHAT CAUSES ERROR
    return {msg};
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Number />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

But if I wrap the return inside a div like this `<div>{msg}</div>` the error goes away. I'm confused why is it so? Because the msg variable has a single parent so the return would also have a single parent, so why do I need that extra div container?

Comment: You cannot return `{msg}` because an object is not a valid child for React. `{msg}` is shorthand for `{msg: msg}`. Returning in `<div></div>` (or even just `msg`) would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By writing like this it's being interpreted as an object with a single key called `msg`.  Without wrapping in JSX tags you  can just write:

```
return msg;
```

The brackets should be used within JSX tags when you need to run a block of javascript or reference a variable.

Comment: But then why does the `div` wrapper solve this problem?

Comment: Because when you wrap with `div` it's now inside JSX tags.  Without wrapping with `div` it is not.

Comment: You can see more about that [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx)